# How to get bag of words from textual data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-processing

I am working on prediction problem using a large textual dataset. I am implementing [Bag of Words Model.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)

What should be the best way to get the bag of words? Right now, I have [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) of the various words and the number of words is too large to use it for further assignments. If I use tf-idf criteria, what should be the tf-idf threshold for getting bag of words? Or should I use some other algorithms. I am using python.

Comment: I'm not following the linked article.  (I don't understand how they go from a dict to the two "vectors" they have).  In any case, you probably will end up using a `collections.Counter` -- although you might want to explain what a `tf-idf` is as well ...

Answer (score 30):

Using the [collections.Counter class](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.Counter)

```
>>> import collections, re
>>> texts = ['John likes to watch movies. Mary likes too.',
             'John also likes to watch football games.']
>>> bagsofwords = [collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', txt))
                   for txt in texts]
>>> bagsofwords[0]
Counter({'likes': 2, 'watch': 1, 'Mary': 1, 'movies': 1, 'John': 1, 'to': 1, 'too': 1})
>>> bagsofwords[1]
Counter({'watch': 1, 'games': 1, 'to': 1, 'likes': 1, 'also': 1, 'John': 1, 'football': 1})
>>> sumbags = sum(bagsofwords, collections.Counter())
>>> sumbags
Counter({'likes': 3, 'watch': 2, 'John': 2, 'to': 2, 'games': 1, 'football': 1, 'Mary': 1, 'movies': 1, 'also': 1, 'too': 1})
>>>
```

Comment: For the bagsofwords[0],  is it possible to access the string "likes" and its count?

Comment: bagsofwords[0]['likes'] should return 2 (untested).

Comment: very nice answer :)

Comment: @RomainJouin Thanks. I remember trying to be terse but try and give the reader avenues to explore. I don't have that particular problem so decided to use the linked wikipedia articles example texts. explanatory variable names cuts the need for comments, and I used straightforward Python which can be quite fast. If it were slow, then I was sure to hear about it :-)

Answer (score 18):

Bag of words could be defined as a matrix where each row represents a document and columns representing the individual token. One more thing, the sequential order of text is not maintained. Building a "Bag of Words" involves 3 steps

1. tokenizing
2. counting
3. normalizing

Limitations to keep in mind:
 1. Cannot capture phrases or multi-word expressions
 2. Sensitive to misspellings, possible to work around that using a spell corrector or character representation,

e.g.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
data_corpus = ["John likes to watch movies. Mary likes movies too.", 
"John also likes to watch football games."]
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_corpus) 
print(X.toarray())
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Comment: We should also select one of the answers close this q ?

Comment: I think this best shows how a BOW really looks compared to the other answers.

```
>>> print(vectorizer.fit_transform(['the cat is blue', 'the dog is blue']).toarray())
[[1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Bag-of-words model is a nice method for text representation to be applied in different machine learning tasks. But in the first step you need to clean up data from unnecessary data for example punctuation, html tags, stop-words,... For these tasks you may can easily exploit libraries like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (to remove HTML Markups) or [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (to remove stop-words) in Python.
 After cleaning your data you need to create a vector features (numerical representation of data for machine learning) this is where Bag-Of-Words plays the role. **scikit-learn** has a module (**feature_extraction** module) which can help you create the bag-of-words features.

You may find all you need in detail in this [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words) also [this](http://radimrehurek.com/data_science_python/) one can be very helpful. I found both of them very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As others already mentioned, using `nltk` would be your best option if you want something stable, and scalable. It's highly configurable.

However, it has the downside of having a quite steep learning curve, if you want to tweak the defaults.

I once encountered a situation where I wanted to have a bag of words. Problem was, it concerned articles about technologies with exotic names full of `-`, `_`, etc. Such as `vue-router` or `_.js` etc.

The default configuration of nltk's `word_tokenize` is to split `vue-router` into two separate `vue` and `router` words, for instance. I'm not even talking about `_.js`.

So for what it's worth, I ended up writing this little routine to get all the words tokenized into a `list`, based on my own punctuation criteria.

```
import re

punctuation_pattern = ' |\.$|\. |, |\/|\(|\)|\'|\"|\!|\?|\+'
text = "This article is talking about vue-router. And also _.js."
ltext = text.lower()
wtext = [w for w in re.split(punctuation_pattern, ltext) if w]

print(wtext)
# ['this', 'article', 'is', 'talking', 'about', 'vue-router', 'and', 'also', '_.js']
```

This routine can be easily combined with Patty3118 answer about `collections.Counter`, which could lead you to know which number of times `_.js` was mentioned in the article, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

From a book "Machine learning python":

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count = CountVectorizer()
docs = np.array(['blablablatext'])
bag = count.fit_transform(docs)
```