# how can i use SVM for text classification without using Tf-idf

Tags: python, svm

I want to classify every entry message.I work with Persian texts. I already implemented a text classifier with Naive Bayes. i did not use `Tf-idf` because every single feature is important for me. But i did some tricks to delete `stop-words` and `pouncs` to have a better accuracy.

I want to implement a text classifier with SVM  but i searched a lot. all I found is related to using pipeline function with the use of `Tf-idf`. like below:

```
model = Pipeline([(‘vectorizer’, CountVectorizer()),
(‘tfidf’, TfidfTransformer()),
(‘clf’, OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(class_weight=”balanced”)))])
```

now, how can i use SVM without Tf-idf?

thanks

Comment: could you provide more about the model you are trying to build? what are your features? words? are you using bag of words of the massage as your data?

Comment: my model include body as text of messages and label. i have 6 labels. yes my data is made of some words that make sentences.@thebeancounter

Answer (score 1):

See here for the sklearn [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) about SVM, there you have a section for multiclass classification using SVM. You first have to convert your texts into a feature vector (numeric, if you wish you use SVM) If you should like to use bag of words you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507172/how-to-get-bag-of-words-from-textual-data) SO question and [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) manual page of sklearn

You can use pre written python code to create BOW from you texts doing something like that - mind you, i geathered the relevant information for the OP - that was unclear and not compatible with SO strandarts, so you might need to work the code a bit for it to fit your excact usage.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> vectorizer                     
CountVectorizer(analyzer=...'word', binary=False, decode_error=...'strict',
        dtype=<... 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=...'utf-8', input=...'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern=...'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)


>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This is the second second document.',
...     'And the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> X                              
<4x9 sparse matrix of type '<... 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse ... format>
```

Then you might need to convert x into a dense matrix (depends on sklearn version) 
Then you could feed x into SVM model you can create like so

```
>>>>from sklearn import svm
>>> X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> Y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale', decision_function_shape='ovo')
>>> clf.fit(X, Y) 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovo', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> dec = clf.decision_function([[1]])
>>> dec.shape[1] # 4 classes: 4*3/2 = 6
6
>>> clf.decision_function_shape = "ovr"
>>> dec = clf.decision_function([[1]])
>>> dec.shape[1] # 4 classes
```